# Why does numpy use the half-open interval for its uniform random?

Tags: python, numpy, random

All of numpy's random functions say things like:

> Create an array of the given shape and propagate it with random
>   samples from a uniform distribution over [0, 1).

(See here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html#numpy.random.rand)

What is the reason for using the half-open interval [0, 1)? From a probabalistic point of view, it shouldn't matter whether 1 is included or not.

Comment: Most random number generators do this. E.g. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_real_distribution/ and https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fNUMBER.html#RANDOM_005fNUMBER

Comment: Note that numpy doesn't actually enforce this across the board: `np.random.uniform(a,b)` claims to be half-open, but `np.random.uniform(0, np.nextafter(0, 1))` will return the upper bound half the time.

Comment: Among other things, it integrates nicely with zero-based arrays.  Multiplying your [0,1) value by the length of your array and `int` it will yield a randomly selected valid array index with equal likelihood for all indices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With arbitrary precision it would indeed not matter, as the probability of reaching any given real number would be zero (non-zero only for an interval).

Computationally it does  matter, since you use finite numerical resolution (e.g. double numbers). So every interval is effectively a closed interval.

Using half-open intervals by default allows you to avoid problems if you stack intervals. So [0,1) and [1,2) will not have common numbers.

For achieving open-open intervals and other concerns see e.g. 
[this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955007/generating-random-numbers-on-open-open-interval-0-1-efficiently)