# Generating random double between 1 and 100 in C

Tags: c

So this works for 10 random integers between 1 and 100:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int random = rand() % 100 + 1;
        printf("The random integer is: %d\n", random);
    }
}
```

However, if I want to randomly generate doubles in the range, how would I go about it? I tried changing the declaration of `random` to `double` and used casting on the RHS like this:

```
double random = (double) rand() % 100 + 1;
```

I hope this question is well formulated.

Comment: The answer I marked a duplicate generates a random number from 0 to 1, but you can multiply by 99 and add 1 to get a random number between 1 and 100.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate random double number in range \[0, 1\] in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62020542/generate-random-double-number-in-range-0-1-in-c)

Comment: Try `drand48` or similar.

Comment: Currently, all answers to this and linked questions, [except one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62021847/509868), have quantization problems - if `RAND_MAX` is 32767, the generated random number will be low-quality. If you really want 52-bit precision, which the type `double` provides, you must make several calls to `rand()`, as described in that answer.

Comment: You want to consider using [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62021847/918959) by Chux, it looks pretty sane and high quality. If you have a really bad random number generator, you can change the `RANDOM_BITS` define to smaler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing would "work", but probably not in the way you intend to. The key is to define what you mean by *random double*. Normally, what we'd mean by this is a double with the maximal precision the system allows.

Fortunately, we know that the number returned by `rand` is between 0 and `RAND_MAX`, whatever that value happens to be. (32767 used to be a common choice.) We can divide by this limit to generate a value between 0 and 1, which then can be scaled to whatever range you need, like so:

```c
double random = ((double) rand() / RAND_MAX) * (100 - 1) + 1;
```

If you wanted a value between 1.5 and 9, you'd do it in a very similar way:

```c
double random = ((double) rand() / RAND_MAX) * (9 - 1.5) + 1.5;
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your suggestion but once I print random 10 times I only seem to get memory addresses, all 9 digits long, some negative some positive.

Comment: @Parseval Remember to print the number as a double, not as an int. (`%g` instead of `%d` as an argument to `printf`.)

Comment: Ah that's so easy to miss for the untrained eye. Thanks a lot man! This cleared everything up!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408990/how-to-generate-random-float-number-in-c